# Algebraic number theory book with answers to selected questions for self-study?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, book-recommendation

Can anyone recommend some easy to follow algebraic number theory books with answers (hints) to selected questions for self-study?

If it has no answers to questions, but if you know that some professors choose the book as a textbook and post answers to selected questions online (as homework solutions), that will be OK too. In this case, can you please give the name of the book and the URL of the course/homework?

Comment: Surely the idea is to have a go at "selected questions" first...

Comment: Also how will you know that any given textbook has selected answers to the same questions you happen to be trying?

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard but not as canonical answer here too. Murty's Problems in Algebraic Number Theory is a good resource, but you need a supplementary resource to learn the material, such as Lang's Algebraic Number Theory.

Answer (score 0):

This is several years too late for the OP, but maybe it will help others with a similar question. *Algebraic Number Theory* by Frazer Jarvis is a very good introductory text with extensive hints and solutions in the appendix. See the [MAA review](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/algebraic-number-theory).